# Why cant PC games be played on Mac

Tags: windows, macos

Need to know if there are technical barriers that requires certain special tools/programming to allow PC games to be played on Mac. Why and what are these tools?

Answer (score 0):

They are different machines running different operating systems.

This analogy may be dated, but it's kind of like asking why your CD player can't play records.